# Send events from AppService to main Project

Tags: voip, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-voip

I am implementing VOIP application. I use this sample [VOIP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VoIP).

when a call changes status, I want to send an event from app service to main project in order to update UI, but I can not find any way to do it, I just can send a message from the main project to app service and receive a response.

So anyone can show me the way to send message from app service to main project ?

Comment: It's not necessary to redundantly include the tag information in the title. Tags work extremely well here in getting the question to the attention of those who follow them; the system doesn't need help. Let it do it's job.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you found the answer to your question elsewhere. I ran into the same issue and I'm starting to think AppServices aren't 100% bidirectional

Comment: Hi @PabloPrado, I have used socket  to send message from appservices to  main project.